# Office 365 SDK for iOS with iOS 7

Tags: ios, office365

I write an app using Office 365 SDK for iOS. It work well with iOS 8 but does not on iOS 7. Please give me some advice

Comment: how does it not work with ios7? Any particular issue that you're facing?

Comment: It always get null when i try to get events. Everything fine with iOS8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run in iOS 7, because in:
.../orc/impl/impl/JsonParser.m
Use code:

-(id)initWith : (objc_property_t)property{

```
NSString *typeString = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getAttributes(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *attributes = [typeString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

self.Type = [attributes objectAtIndex:0];
self.Name = [NSString  stringWithCString:property_getName(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if([self.Name containsString:@"$$$_$$$"]) return nil;

if ([self isComplexType]) {
    self.SubStringType = [self.Type substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [self.Type length] -4)];
}
return self;
```

}

containsString is  function of NSString class which is exist in iOS 8, not support in iOS7.

Comment: It's seem like a a proper answer. I just wonder, how do you figure it out?

Comment: I got similar when i use SDK to build app in iOS 7 => app crash, So, i figure it out when i debug it.